# Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter using AND and OR

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap-query

I'm trying to build a script, a portion of which will select users by a couple of variables and put them into a variable as an array. The users must have "CONTRACTOR" in their description and their reporting manager must be one of four individuals. I have gotten the script to work when matching the "CONTRACTOR" description and a single reporting manager. Here is an example of what I'm doing.

```
$ADAccounts = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(description=CONTRACTOR)|(manager=CN=Manager1 Name,OU=Users,OU=Location,OU=USA,DC=domain,DC=com)(manager=CN=Manager2 Name,OU=Users,OU=Location,OU=USA,DC=domain,DC=com))"
```

I'm sure what I'm missing is simple, but I haven't been able to find it when looking through other posts. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like with `&`, you need to group the clauses together under a single clause with the `|` operator as the *first* element:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(&(description=CONTRACTOR)(|(manager=CN=Manager1 Name,OU=Users,OU=Location,OU=USA,DC=domain,DC=com)(manager=CN=Manager2 Name,OU=Users,OU=Location,OU=USA,DC=domain,DC=com)))'
```

Comment: I was just playing around with it and got it to work...using exactly what you just said here. Thanks for your input. I know I was missing something simple.